# css find first child gives wrong result

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I have:

```
<ul>
<li id="test1">The third paragraph.</li>
<li id="test1">The fourth paragraph.</li>
<li id="test2">The second paragraph.</li>
<li id="test2">The third paragraph.</li>
<li id="test2">The fourth paragraph.</li>
<li id="test3">The second paragraph.</li>
<li id="test3">The third paragraph.</li>
<li id="test4">The fourth paragraph.</li>
<li id="test4">The fourth paragraph.</li>
<li id="test7">The fourth paragraph.</li>
<li id="test7">The fourth paragraph.</li>
</ul>
```

And css code:

```
ul > #test4:first-child
{
background:#ff0000;
}
```

This code ul > #test1:first-child is good but  ul > #test4:first-child not working

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/sunukatu/1/edit?html,css,output)
where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ID of an element must be unique,

Second [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-child) will match only the first child element irrespective any other selector used for the child element, so in your case the first #test1 will be the only element matched by `ul > :first-child` selector

I don't think there is a css only solution for this.

Instead of ID use class attribute, then use the [:first-selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector) in jQuery like

```
.someclass{
    //some rule
}
```

then

```
$('ul > .test4:first').addClass('someclass')
```

Comment: I second this [I was going to suggest this myself, and then you edited :)]

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you are looking for a `:first-child` of the `<ul>` element which has an id named `test4`. What you want is the first element with id `test4` and I think that's not possible with pure CSS.

Also, you should better use classes instead of IDs since you shouldn't repeat IDs in HTML elements.